# joining monthly values with daily values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join

I have daily values in one table and monthly values in another table. I need to use the values of the monthly table and calculate them on a daily basis.

basically, monthly factor * daily factor -- for each day

thanks!

I have a table like this:

```
2010-12-31 00:00:00.000 28.3
2010-09-30 00:00:00.000 64.1
2010-06-30 00:00:00.000 66.15
2010-03-31 00:00:00.000 12.54
```

and a table like this :

```
2010-12-31 00:00:00.000 98.1
2010-12-30 00:00:00.000 97.61
2010-12-29 00:00:00.000 99.03
2010-12-28 00:00:00.000 97.7
2010-12-27 00:00:00.000 96.87
2010-12-23 00:00:00.000 97.44
2010-12-22 00:00:00.000 97.76
2010-12-21 00:00:00.000 96.63
2010-12-20 00:00:00.000 95.47
2010-12-17 00:00:00.000 95.2
2010-12-16 00:00:00.000 94.84
2010-12-15 00:00:00.000 94.8
2010-12-14 00:00:00.000 94.1
2010-12-13 00:00:00.000 93.88
2010-12-10 00:00:00.000 93.04
2010-12-09 00:00:00.000 91.07
2010-12-08 00:00:00.000 90.89
2010-12-07 00:00:00.000 92.72
2010-12-06 00:00:00.000 93.05
2010-12-03 00:00:00.000 91.74
2010-12-02 00:00:00.000 90.74
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000 90.25
```

I need to take the value for the quarter and multiply it buy all the days in the quarter by the daily value

Comment: I see no question. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please add schema, sample data and a desired result. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
SELECT dt.day, dt.factor*mt.factor AS daily_factor
FROM daily_table dt INNER JOIN month_table mt
    ON YEAR(dt.day) = YEAR(mt.day)
   AND FLOOR((MONTH(dt.day)-1)/3) = FLOOR((MONTH(mt.day)-1)/3)
ORDER BY dt.day
```

or (as suggested by @Andriy)

```
SELECT dt.day, dt.factor*mt.factor AS daily_factor
FROM daily_table dt INNER JOIN month_table mt
    ON YEAR(dt.day) = YEAR(mt.day)
   AND DATEPART(QUARTER, dt.day) = DATEPART(QUARTER, mt.day)
ORDER BY dt.day
```

Comment: to be safer you should probably also add the year into the schema and join

Comment: @paul: yes, thanks... I changed the whole answer according to OP schema and data

Comment: Ideally, `DATEPART(QUARTER, dt.day) = DATEPART(QUARTER, mt.day)` should work just as well as `FLOOR((MONTH(dt.day)-1)/3) = FLOOR((MONTH(mt.day)-1)/3)`, and even better, since, to obtain the number of the quarter from a number of a month, you would need to delete the latter by `4`, not by `3`. :)

Comment: @AndriyM: I edited my answer and I thank you for finding a better solution. Anyway I'm pretty sure I have to use `/3`: think about month from july to september, they are 7..9, with -1 they become 6..8 and /3+FLOOR it's always 2, while using /4 it's not....

Comment: Ah, sorry, the mistake was mine indeed, and a really silly one too.

Comment: Anyway, there's another thing you might be unaware of but might find useful: in SQL Server, integral division is automatically used when both operand of `/` are integers. That means you don't really need `FLOOR()` (although it doesn't change anything either, and would be useful in making the script portable to, say, MySQL).

Comment: @AndriyM: I didn't know this, thanks. Anyway I'm not sure about portability: are you sure that other db (e.g. MySql) directly cast division to integer? Maybe, I didn't try.. :)

Comment: @AndriyM: anyway database schema is definitely wrong... why OP stores a datetime if he needs year and quarter? Queries will be easier and data clearer using two int fields (smallint maybe)...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I actually meant that *leaving `FLOOR` in the query* would make no change (compared to omitting it) and would make the query portable to MySQL.

Comment: I don't know what reasons the OP might have to stick with `datetime` instead of two `int`s, but I might choose the same design because because that way it is easier to make calculations (add a quarter or half a year), while year and quarter can be derived from the result. With `int`s the calculations would probably be more cumbersome.